# Design a flashing circuit that uses PWM signal and MCU signal to control when it is on and off

Tags: mosfet, digital-logic, pic, pwm, low-voltage

My team and I are working on the low voltage systems of a solar car and have an issue with figuring out how to flash the turn signals on the car. The options we are exploring include:

- Using a 555 timer to create the PWM then feeding this to an NMOS circuit which is used to turn on another NMOS circuit. (This caused many issues specifically if the output pin voltage at the gate from the MCU was <5 V since using a High side then Low side switch brings in some issues)
- An alternative could be using the MCU to generate the PWM and using a LOWSIDE switch (a very simple design)
- Or we were thinking of using an electronic turn signal flasher, that would be controlled by the microcontroller.

It would be amazing if we could get some insight into suggestions related or unrelated to the ones discussed above.

For the LEDs we are using the custom dynamic TF20 amber lights.

Sample circuit is below. This image shows the circuit being tested, the drain of the MOSFET connected to the output of a 555 timer while the gate to an MCU and the source to the gate of the other MOSFET.

[image: This image shows the circuit being tested, the drain of the mosfet connect to the output of a 555timer while the gate to a MCU and the source to the gate of the other mosfet]

Comment: The convention with automotive is to use a high side switch as the chassis is used for the return path. This may not be the case with a solar vehicle, so the low side switch would be more convenient. If you use a 'smart' mosfet, these have built in drive and protection circuitry which makes your job easier. They are significantly more expensive but are common in automotive applications. For flashing, you could use pwm, but my first thought would be to have a timer tick at 10ms and simply count ticks to determine the on/off ratio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you want a 1/2 second on, half-second off or near that. I also assume that since you're looking for a low-power solution since you're solar powered.

Assuming that you have 5 or 3.3 volts available, it's really hard to beat a tiny 8-bit microcontroller feeding a MOSFET low-side switch. Set up a timer and put the uC in a sleep state between timer ticks. Use one for both turn signals (with two MOSFETS) and have GPIO inputs to turn them on and off.